# DISKPART I accidentally used the CLEAN command on my computer

Tags: windows-7

When using DISKPART I accidentally used the CLEAN command on my computer . Now it is no showing any other drive expect C drive .Pl tell me how can i resolve this issue to get back the original Position,Any undo commend.Thanks and regades,Chandrabhanu

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what you really want to do is to boot a live linux distribution of your choice and backup the whole disk via dd to some external drive. You can then use that image for your further experiments.

I've restored quite a lot of drives with lost partitions in the past using [TestDisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestDisk), so you might want to look into that. [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415) says that you probably only destroyed only MBR or GPT - whatever you're using - data, so I'm pretty certain that TestDisk can revert that for you.